# PHP file creation/write within destructor

Tags: php, caching, serialization, destructor

When calling `file_put_contents()` within a destructor, it causes files to be written in `SERVER_ROOT`... (Yikes!)  Workarounds?

tldr:

I want to cache an array, probably containing serialized class instances.  I figured, for now, I would write a class that implements the cache using `unserialize()/file_get_contents()` and `serialize()/file_put_contents()` and then hide its functionality behind a more generic Cache class. (I don't know if my client's host will have shared memory or PEAR, etc)

```
<?php
    class CacheFile {
        private $filename;
        private $data;
        private $dirty = false;

        function __construct($filename) {
            $this->filename = $filename;
            $this->load();
        }

        function __destruct() {
            // Calling file_put_contents within a destructor causes files to be written in SERVER_ROOT...
            $this->flush();
        }

        private function load() {
            if(!file_exists($this->filename)) {
                $this->data = array();
            }
            else {
                $this->data = unserialize(file_get_contents($this->filename));
                // todo
            }
            $this->dirty = false;
        }

        private function persist() {
            file_put_contents($this->filename, serialize($this->data));
            $this->dirty = false;
        }

        public function get($key) {
            if(array_key_exists($key, $this->data)) {
                return $this->data[$key];
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public function set($key, $value) {
            if(!array_key_exists($key, $this->data)) {
                $dirty = true;
            }
            else if($this->data[$key] !== $value) {
                $dirty = true;
            }
            if($dirty) {
                $this->dirty = true;
                $this->data[$key] = $value;
            }
        }

        public function flush() {
            if($this->dirty) {
                $this->persist();
            }
        }
    }


    $cache = new CacheFile("cache");
    var_dump( $cache->get("item") );
    $cache->set("item", 42);
    //$cache->flush();
    var_dump( $cache->get("item") );
?>
```

See the call to `flush()` in the destructor?  I really don't want to have the `public flush()` function because it's implementation-specific.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but why is `SERVER_ROOT` writable by the web server user?

Comment: what is in `$this->filename` ?

Comment: I changed the code in the OP to show the issue in action... $this->filename is "cache"

Comment: About SERVER_ROOT, I do wonder what would happen if you did this on shared hosting :P

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I assume you have not specified a full qualified path in `$this->filename`.

On some PHP configurations, when destructors are called (in the scripts shutdown phase), the working directory can change. Relative paths resolve to another location then.

Compare with the related note in the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php):

> **Note:**
>
> Destructors called during the script shutdown have HTTP headers already sent. The working directory in the script shutdown phase can be different with some SAPIs (e.g. Apache).

If you make that path absolute, it will work as expected.

**Edit:** As you've update your code, this is a simple way to ensure you've got the absolute path:

```
$cache = new CacheFile(realpath("cache"));
```

Or much better *within* the constructor:

```
$this->filename = realpath($filename);
```

Comment: @Brandon: I've added a small code chunk that relates to the line of code in your updated question. `realpath()` creates an absolute filename of a relative one.

Comment: Awesome, I think that solves the problem of what will happen when I pass an absolute path to the constructor

Answer (score 2):

You could [create a file handle](http://php.net/fopen) in `load()` which you can use in `__destruct()` or `flush()`.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a relative path as $filename? I would pass in an absolute path to where you want the file. If you want it to be relative to where your script is you could use something like:

```
$filename = dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']) . PATH_SEPARATOR . $filename;
```

Comment: Why not just use `__DIR__` ?