# How to emulate __destruct() in a static class?

Tags: php, design-patterns, static, class-design

I've coded a simple configuration class for my own framework.

There are simple functions like `get()`, `set()` or `loadFile()`.
But all functions and variables are static.

And now I want to implement an autosave mechanism. I had the idea to create an instance (in my init() function) whose `__destruct()` will call the static `destruct()` function:

```
<?php

class Config
{
  static private $autoSave;
  static public function get() {} /* set(), save(), load(), etc. */

  static public function init($autoSave)
  {
    self::$autoSave = $autoSave;
    new Config();
  }
  static public function destruct()
  {
    if (self::$autoSave)
      self::save();
  }

  public function __destruct()
  {
    Config::destruct();
  }
}

?>
```

Are there any better solutions or is my design pattern completely wrong in this case?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Are there any better solutions or is my design pattern completely wrong in this case?

Destructors are called on objects only, not for static classes.

Instead you could convert your class from static to regular so you can create an instance of it. Then it will have the destructor. Additionally it makes your code easier to re-use and test.

Additionally you're able to implement magic methods for `__get` and `__set` or `ArrayAccess` which often is useful for easy data storage and access as for a configuration.

Alternatively, you can add a destructor object to a static class member to achieve what you're looking for:

```
class ConfigDestructor
{
  public function __destruct()
  {
    Config::destruct();
  }
}

class Config
{
  static private $destructorInstance;
  static private $autoSave;
  static public function get() {} /* set(), save(), load(), etc. */

  static public function init($autoSave)
  {
    if (null === self::$destructorInstance) 
        self::$destructorInstance = new ConfigDestructor();

    self::$autoSave = $autoSave;
  }
  static public function destruct()
  {
    if (self::$autoSave)
      self::save();
  }
}
```

Just FYI: You wrote you want to add an auto-save functionality. There is a common gap to fall over for both `__destruct()` and [`register_shutdown_function`](http://php.net/register_shutdown_function):

> **Note:** Working directory of the script can change inside the shutdown function under some web servers, e.g. Apache.

You should specify an absolute path to access the file you want to save into. See as well: [PHP file creation/write within destructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6629061/php-file-creation-write-within-destructor/6629226).

Comment: I already know that function but I thought there other ways. And I've built a workaround for the path, too. I simply save a file handle by loading.

BTW at first my class hasn't any static functions, I've converted it to the code above.

Comment: @user603003: I just added a way to do it with a `ConfigDestructor` object if you really want to stay static. But I highly recommend you don't static class functions that generally, but make the configuration work as an object.

Comment: So I use my first code which contained 100% object-oriented functions.

Answer (score 8):

Inside your `init` method, add a call to [`register_shutdown_function`](http://php.net/register_shutdown_function):

```
register_shutdown_function(array('Config', 'destruct'));
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at [register_shutdown_function](http://php.net/register_shutdown_function)? You could add your method to the shutdown part of the script.

It could also be worth it to look at the [Singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).

Comment: Yes, but I didn't want to reserve the function for the config class.

Comment: You may have several shutdown functions registered, if that's your worry. Registering one does not unregister the previously registered  ones, if that's what you meant by "reserve".

Comment: Well if one of those shutdown functions calls `exit()` the others aren't called any further - `__destruct()` is immune against that behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an instance of this static class on autoregister.

```
$instance = array();
spl_autoload_register(function ($class)
{
    ...
    global $instance;
    if ($isStatic) $instance[] = new $class();
    ...
});
```

This is working fine for me.

... and for those who don't like readable code (it is untested):

```
class staticInstances()
{
    private static $list = array();

    public static function add($class)
    {
        self::$list[] = new $class();
    }

    function __distruct()
    {
        foreach (self::$list as $class)
            unset(self::$list);
    }
}
$staticInstances = new staticInstances();

spl_autoload_register(function ($class)
{
    ...
    if ($isStatic) staticInstances::add($class);
    ...
});
```

Comment: Wow, an answer even 1 year after I asked the question. Your code might work fine, but it's using global variables - a thing which a programmer should avoid.

Comment: then build a class with a static function addclass() and instanciate this class. but this is an overkill in my opinion. it is my only global variable. remember k.i.s.s. as often as possible. this doesnt mean to be lazy.